# How do I change emacs application name from "Emacs" to something else in OSX?

Tags: osx, emacs

I run multiple emacs instances with `open -n -a Emacs.app` command. The problem is that it's hard to distinguish between them when you switch with Cmd+Tab, because they're all named "Emacs" there.

How do I change the name of specific emacs instance in Cmd-Tab list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set-frame-name` function in Emacs, i.e. press <kbd>M-x</kbd>`set-frame-name`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then type in any name you like, and finish with <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm doing in Ubuntu, but it doesn't change name inside Cmd-Tab list in OSX, it's still just "Emacs". // emacs was installed via brew